# change user roles in Azure AD using React app UI

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-ad-msal

I have a sample React SPA hosted on Azure that is using MSAL authentication. There would be different user permissions based on user role. Is there a way to change user roles (i.e. add or exclude user from AD group) using UI in my app. Is it done by calling graph API somehow? Maybe some example code you could show me?

The goal is to demo different app functionality for different user roles but dynamically change those roles in the app without going to Azure AD and manually assign roles to the user who is testing this app.

I need to be able to add logged in user into one of the groups on App registration from inside my react app and update interface when user role changes

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qkbz.png]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems you may run into with this approach.

- How does your app read the users roles. If it caches the user roles on login, then you need to logout and login again for the changes to take effect.
- If the user is allowed to change their group membership in AD, then this opens a security issue.

For the purpose of your demo I would:

- Have 2 browsers open. One with the user and one with Azure AD admin.
- Show what the user can do
- User log out
- Change roles in AD
- User log in
- Show what the user can do with the new role

Comment: Yes, this is how I do it now. Although I was looking for a way to programmatically change user roles from React App (understanding that in real application I would not want this scenario for security reasons, etc.) This is to demo MSAL authentication in my app all from the same UI.